# Doc for setting up Prometheus Alertmanager in Go App?

Tags: go, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Functionality broken and client signatures are vastly different while upgrading Alertmanager from 0.21.0 to 0.24.0. There seems no good documentation for setting it up with v0.24.0 too.

Is there a doc which provides an example to set this up for v0.24.0?